# mysql is not up when it was started?

Tags: mysql

when i am starting up MySQL galera cluster in one of 3 nodes ,it  has not yet come up , Below error message was well found from error log
after that i tried to rebuilding my box from another source again we are getting same issue.

```
stack_bottom = 4cc4b098 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x7d08b5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4b4)[0x6a90e4]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x2aec71ffdb10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5453c7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x545a10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x545ca6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x53d859]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16acl_authenticateP3THDjj+0x8c0)[0x54ca20]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x639a5e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16login_connectionP3THD+0x50)[0x639c70]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z22thd_prepare_connectionP3THD+0x2f)[0x639e7f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x12b)[0x63af1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x51)[0x63b121]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x2aec71ff573d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x2aec733460cd]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 18
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

i was followed below link and recieved preceeding result.

```
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-stack-trace.html
```

Result

```
0x40000 (?)
0x7d08b5 my_print_stacktrace + 53
0x6a90e4 handle_fatal_signal + 1204
0x2aec71ffdb10 _end + 1895256184
0x5453c7 _Z7get_mqhPKcS0_P9user_conn + 1527
0x545a10 _Z7get_mqhPKcS0_P9user_conn + 3136
0x545ca6 _Z7get_mqhPKcS0_P9user_conn + 3798
0x53d859 _Z23get_cached_table_accessP22st_grant_internal_infoPKcS2_ + 233
0x54ca20 _Z16acl_authenticateP3THDjj + 2240
0x639a5e _Z30check_for_max_user_connectionsP3THDPK9user_conn + 750
0x639c70 _Z16login_connectionP3THD + 80
0x639e7f _Z22thd_prepare_connectionP3THD + 47
0x63af1b _Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD + 299
0x63b121 handle_one_connection + 81
0x2aec71ff573d _end + 1895222437
0x2aec733460cd _end + 1915475509
```

Please help me how to fix it.

Comment: mysql is not sql server

Comment: and [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering) is a data mining technique. maybe you meant [tag:load-balancing]? Please tag more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

1、In mysql configuration file by adding the following line configuration, try

```
thread_cache_size=8
```

Comment: currently we are using thread_cache_size=512 and i was changed to 8 and tried but no luck same error we are getting.                                                                      [mysql@qa2 ~]$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
[mysql@qa2 ~]$ less ./log/mysqld.error